# TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'> for StructuredDataAdapter

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, auto-keras

can anyone help me to resolve above error?

```py
### using trasnformers 
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
         [
          ('CompanyName_bow', TfidfVectorizer(), 'CompanyName'),
          ('state_category', OneHotEncoder(), ['state']),
          ('Termination_Reason_Desc_bow', TfidfVectorizer(), 'Termination_Reason_Desc'),
          ('TermType_category', OneHotEncoder(), ['TermType'])
         ],
         remainder=MinMaxScaler()
        )
X = column_trans.fit_transform(X.head(100))

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y.head(100))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=5)

X_train.shape  #(80, 92)
X_test.shape   #(20, 92)
y_train.shape  #(80,)
X_train.todense()
matrix([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.26921709, 1.        ,
         0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         1.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.46148896, 1.        ,
         0.        ],
        ...,
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.46148896, 1.        ,
         0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         1.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.46148896, 1.        ,
         0.        ]])

type(X_train)
--> scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

print(y_train)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
 
type(y_train)
numpy.ndarray

# use autokeras to find a model for the sonar dataset
from numpy import asarray
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from autokeras import StructuredDataClassifier

print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
# define the search
search = StructuredDataClassifier(max_trials=15)
# perform the search
search.fit(x=(X_train), y=y_train, verbose=0)
# evaluate the model
loss, acc = search.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %.3f' % acc)
```

**Error**

```py
(80, 92) (20, 92) (80,) (20,)
INFO:tensorflow:Reloading Oracle from existing project .\structured_data_classifier\oracle.json
INFO:tensorflow:Reloading Tuner from .\structured_data_classifier\tuner0.json
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-94708e5d279d> in <module>
     10 search = StructuredDataClassifier(max_trials=15)
     11 # perform the search
---> 12 search.fit(x=(X_train), y=y_train, verbose=0)
     13 # evaluate the model
     14 loss, acc = search.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\autokeras\tasks\structured_data.py in fit(self, x, y, epochs, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, **kwargs)
    313                 [keras.Model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit).
    314         """
--> 315         super().fit(
    316             x=x,
    317             y=y,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\autokeras\tasks\structured_data.py in fit(self, x, y, epochs, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, **kwargs)
    132         self.check_in_fit(x)
    133 
--> 134         super().fit(
    135             x=x,
    136             y=y,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\autokeras\auto_model.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, **kwargs)
    259             validation_split = 0
    260 
--> 261         dataset, validation_data = self._convert_to_dataset(
    262             x=x, y=y, validation_data=validation_data, batch_size=batch_size
    263         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\autokeras\auto_model.py in _convert_to_dataset(self, x, y, validation_data, batch_size)
    373             x = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x)
    374             y = dataset.map(lambda x, y: y)
--> 375         x = self._adapt(x, self.inputs, batch_size)
    376         y = self._adapt(y, self._heads, batch_size)
    377         dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x, y))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\autokeras\auto_model.py in _adapt(self, dataset, hms, batch_size)
    287         adapted = []
    288         for source, hm in zip(sources, hms):
--> 289             source = hm.get_adapter().adapt(source, batch_size)
    290             adapted.append(source)
    291         if len(adapted) == 1:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\autokeras\engine\adapter.py in adapt(self, dataset, batch_size)
     65             tf.data.Dataset. The converted dataset.
     66         """
---> 67         self.check(dataset)
     68         dataset = self.convert_to_dataset(dataset, batch_size)
     69         return dataset

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\autokeras\adapters\input_adapters.py in check(self, x)
     63     def check(self, x):
     64         if not isinstance(x, (pd.DataFrame, np.ndarray, tf.data.Dataset)):
---> 65             raise TypeError(
     66                 "Unsupported type {type} for "
     67                 "{name}.".format(type=type(x), name=self.__class__.__name__)

TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'> for StructuredDataAdapter.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noticed in the [Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/autokeras/issues/1521) you opened in parallel with this thread, sparse matrices are not (currently) supported in AutoKeras, and the advice is to convert them to dense Numpy arrays. Indeed, from the [documentation](https://autokeras.com/structured_data_classifier/) of AutoKeras `StructuredDataClassifier`, the training data `x` in the respective `.fit` method are expected to be:

> String, numpy.ndarray, pandas.DataFrame or tensorflow.Dataset

and not SciPy sparse matrix.

Given that here your `X_train` is really small:

```py
X_train.shape  
# (80, 92)
```

you have absolutely no reason whatsoever to use a sparse matrix. And although here you seem to try to convert `X_train` to a dense one, you do not *re-assign* it, the result being that it remains a sparse one; from your own code above:

```py
X_train.todense()
# ...
type(X_train)
# scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

What you need to do is simply to reassign it to a dense array:

```py
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
X_train = X_train.toarray()
```

Here is a short demo that this works with dummy data:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
X_train = csr_matrix((3, 4), dtype=np.float)

type(X_train)
# scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

# this will not work:
X_train.todense()
type(X_train)
# scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix # still sparse

# this will work:
X_train = X_train.toarray()
type(X_train)
# numpy.ndarray
```

You should follow a similar procedure for your `X_test` data (your `y_train` and `y_test` seem to be already dense Numpy arrays).

Answer (score -2):

The possible reason (due to the low readability of your code pasted above) could be using different datasets with saved models. I suggest you add `overwrite=True` in the `BayesianOptimization` construction code block. Reinstalling TensorFlow may also help.

Comment: same X and y variable are working with deep learning but it is not working on aurokeras StructuredDataClassifier

Comment: i don't think it is related to tensorflow. please let me know if you want more specification related to above error?

Comment: Can you please tell what are the files included in the directory in which you wrote the code just go to the terminal and cd to the path of the folder and use dir and please do share what it echos.

Comment: And try adding overwrite=True in tuner = kt.Hyperband( build_model, objective = 'val_accuracy', max_epochs=10, hyperband_iterations=2 )